# EntityManager null and NullPointerException while searching in DB

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, netbeans-7

i am really noob in java ee

i want to make a query to verify if email is unique

after i search on web i mad i came to conclusion that me EntityManeger is null

this is my **entity Customer** and is an query **Customer.findByEmail** that is my point of focus

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findById", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.id = :id"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByName", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.name = :name"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByEmail", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.email = :email"),
(...)
```

i have a **session named CutomerFacade**

```
@Stateless
public class CustomerFacade extends AbstractFacade<Customer> {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "AffableBeanPU")
public EntityManager em;

public List<Customer> GetPorEmail(String match){
   return  em.createNamedQuery("Customer.findByEmail").setParameter("email", match).getResultList();
}
```

Whats the solution to avoid **null in entity manager**

Comment: Ok, I want to see your persistence.xml. Please post the file content, Regards

Comment: As well as your EntityManagerFactory definition.

Comment: i already got the answer for the problem and its the location where i call the session bean, i change the web.xml and now i call in the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you are running in a Java EE server and accessing the SessionBean through the container.

What server are you running in?  How do you access the SessionBean?

Comment: i use the glashfish server on port 8080, i change the web.xml, i access the session bean in controller